# Postgresql: LIKE and partition by fields of the initial table

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning, postgresql-12

I have an already existing table which I want to partition, looking at the documentation I see that this cannot happen, so I re-created the table and try to partition that:

```
CREATE TABLE tableB (LIKE tableA INCLUDING ALL) PARTITION BY range (field1_in_tableA, field2_in_tableA);
```

but I am getting:

```
ERROR:  insufficient columns in PRIMARY KEY constraint definition
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "tableB" lacks column "field1_in_tableA" which is part of the partition key.
```

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a primary key, then you can't partition by a key which is not part of the primary key. Do you want a primary key on the new table? If so, you have to either add field1_in_tableA to the primary key, or remove it from the partitioning key.

Comment: > If you have a primary key, then you can't partition by a key which is not part of the primary key

I see. Is this mentioned somewhere in the documentation though?

Comment: "Unique constraints on partitioned tables must include all the partition key columns. This limitation exists because PostgreSQL can only enforce uniqueness in each partition individually." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html